# How to add Horizontal Scrollbar in Winform application to compatibility in all screen sizes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winform application.The dimensions of the winform window is `1300*715` as my user inputs fields are getting adjusted in this space.Now the application is dispalying fine in big screen system but in small screen it is getting reduced from the right so the user input fields present there is not visible to the user.Also it is giving very bad look of the application.
So my question is that Can we put any horizontal scrollbar into Winform application so that small screen users can scroll and see the full application or is there any better way to rectify this as `Responsive` concept is there in web.

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`AutoScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a62htd5x(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the form to true but I personally think you should look at changing the UI.

**MSDN** Remarks:

> If this property is set to **true**, scroll bars are displayed on the form
> if any controls are located outside the form's client region.
>
> Additionally, when autoscrolling is on, the client area of the form
> automatically scrolls to make the control with input focus visible.
> You can use this property to prevent users from losing the ability to
> view controls when their video resolution settings are set to a low
> resolution.

Comment: off topic but...wow, that's cool.  i didnt know you could edit someone else's post.  you learn something new everyday.

Comment: Yes. You could edit questions as well. Make the questions more understandable and to the point with valid formatting. However this requires approval from the OP. Have a look on the topics present in meta stackoverflow as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the form DPI to Font and the container which holds the windows controls like panel has a property AutoScroll it must be set to true.
Like  Panel1.AutoScroll=true;
If the form is container set it's AutoScroll property to true;